# Error when logging into FTP from AsyncTask class using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ftp

I am logging into the ftp account using AsyncTask but I keep getting this error,

```
12-31 15:26:19.637: E/dalvikvm(5986): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient', referenced from method com.example.testme.Processing.connnectingwithFTP
```

I can understand that my method inside Asynctask is not able to find the FTPClient class eventhough it is imported fine. But I don't how to make my inner AsyncTask method find the FTPClient class.

Here is my code,

**AsyncTask class**

```
class Processing extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        connnectingwithFTP("host", "username",
                "password");
        return null;
    }

    public void connnectingwithFTP(String ip, String userName, String pass) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();

            mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ip));
            status = mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);
            Log.e("isFTPConnected", String.valueOf(status));
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtpClient.getReplyCode())) {
                mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
                mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                FTPFile[] mFileArray = mFtpClient.listFiles();
                Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(mFileArray.length));
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I am doing in `onCreate` method,

```
Processing p1 = new Processing();
        p1.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the jar file to the `libs` folder of your project. Also, make sure it's checked under the `Order and Export` tab.

Comment: I have already imported it by going to project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External jars

Comment: Is it checked under the `Order and Export` tab?